# How to connect Dear inventory APIs and Google sheet?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I would like to connect the Dear inventory system with Google Sheets for importing product lists, Sale lists data, etc by using both the Dear API and Google Sheets API.
It should be automatically updated.
Is it possible or not?
If yes, Any methods here?

Comment: Should be possible. But  there's no ready made method. Someone has to work for hours.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible. With this you have a generic setup that will NOT handle nested objects or arrays. But you can create specific functions with the data you want. But for that you should hire somebody, or do the work yourself.

The setup is that you can use the generic function to get the endpoint you want to the sheet you want. `dearAPI(endpoint, sheetname, dig)`

Dig: This is the object that holds the array of the returned data:

[image: Screenshot of returned JSON data.]

**The code:**

```
//GLOBAL variables:
const accountID = 'id';
const secret = 'secret';

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('DEAR')
    .addItem('Update all', 'updateAll')
    .addToUi();
}

function updateAll(){
  dearAPI('product','Products','Products');
  dearAPI('salesList','Sales', 'SalesList');
}


/**
* Updates data from specific DEAR endpoint to specific sheet.
*
* @param {string} endpoint - the endpoint the get the data from.
* @param {string} sheetname - name of the sheet to write the data to.
* @param {string} dig - the object where the array of data is returned.
* @return {void}
*/
function dearAPI(endpoint, sheetname, dig) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname)

  const dataRows = [];
  let pagenumber = 1;

  do {
  const url = `https://inventory.dearsystems.com/externalapi/v2/${endpoint}?page=${pagenumber}&limit=1000`;
  const headers = {
    "api-auth-accountid": accountID,
    "api-auth-applicationkey": secret
  };
  
  const options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers 
  };

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
  data[dig].forEach(item => dataRows.push(item));
  pagenumber++
  } while (data.Total != data.Page)

  const rowHeaders = Object.keys(dataRows[0]);
  const rows = [rowHeaders];
  for (let i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++) {
    const rowData = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < rowHeaders.length; j++) {
      rowData.push(dataRows[i][rowHeaders[j]]); 
    }
    rows.push(rowData);
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,rows.length,rows[0].length).setValues(rows); 

}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help!!! But when I tried this code, I got an error in this line    data[dig].forEach(item => dataRows.push(item));
  pagenumber++ 
likes TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined